# "A specialist product" or "a specific product"

Tags: vocabulary

I was reading an article and this sentence seems strange to me:

"...understands that **specialist** products are required that will withstand intensive use and..."

I would use the word "specific" instead of "specialist".
Can specialist be used in this case? I always believed specialised meant like an expert.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It means more than *specific* - the products are designed by experts to serve an exact purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand better now.

Comment: Or perhaps "intended for use by specialists".